# The Xcode xcshareddata directory?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

My project now has a `project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata` directory.

What does Xcode store in the `project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata` directory?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `xcshareddata` directory is primarily used to store shared settings (as opposed to `xcuserdata` which is used for settings which are not shared a.k.a. user specific). The following are some items currently stored in 'xcshareddata`:

- Schemes: schemes can be shared in Xcode with the "Scheme manager" which can be accessed via the "Product" > "Scheme" > "Manage Schemes" menu items. Schemes have a "share" option.
- Breakpoints:
  1.) In the breakpoint navigator, Control-click the breakpoint.
  2.) From the shortcut menu, choose Share Breakpoint.
- xccheckout: A file that contains metadata about what repositories are used in a workspace. In the case of workspaces that have multiple projects from different repositories Xcode uses an .xccheckout file to know what all of the components that make up a workspace are and where to get them.

Comment: So, don't check it in to source control, right?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on your project and teams workflow but since the data is meant to be shared, I check it in to "share" it.